# Can "keep" be used as a synonym for "last" or "endure"?

Tags: word-usage

In an English-language text I wrote recently, I used this sentence

> It ain't pretty, but it'll keep!

to describe the durability of a newly erected wall that (due to my poor masonry skills) looks hideous, but should withstand the  floods it'll be shielding the property against.

In my native German dialect, this is a valid use of "keep."

But is it actually in English, too?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it that I can see.

Comment: If you were saying that your wall was merely of indifferent quality, you might say that *it will do*, meaning *suffice*. *Keep* in this context describes durability rather than quality, as you say, although the word is most frequently used with respect to food - how soon it needs to be eaten.

Comment: Eat that cake now, because it won't keep.  (But your sample sentence isn't really idiomatic.  This sense of "keep" is mostly used to describe foodstuffs and other perishable items.)

Comment: That was my suspicion, thanks! That might make a valid answer....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "keep" can be used to refer to something that will maintain its structure or condition. Your use refers to the wall continuing to stand, despite a lack of aesthetic refinement. Alternatively, you can use the term "hold".

The phrase "do the trick" could also be used if you prefer to emphasize the utility (keeping the flood water out) versus the sturdiness of the structure.

Comment: This use of 'keep' is clear - it also sounds folksy and dialectal.

Comment: it's perfectly acceptable to a native speaker,  but it's also *very* idiomatic.

Answer (score -1):

Yes , keep can be used as a synonym for last or endure because if you want to make something last you keep it , leaving keep and last to have almost the same meaning and that's whY a synonym is  two words that have the same meaning or mean almost about the same thing .